# Sidekiq Pro callback when batch is retried?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq pro for my application, and it's been working great. But I'd like to have a way to notify my users that a failed job is being retried.

A flow would go something like this:

`Batch starts
worker1 runs successfully
worker2 runs successfully
worker3 fails
oncomplete fires, stuff happens
worker3 restarts
** onretry fires, notification sent to user
worker 3 runs successfully
onsuccess fires, stuff happens`

My imaginary onretry doesn't exist in the documentation but I'm hoping there's a way to fake it. I know that I can tell if the batch has failures via the status object, but I don't see a way to get a retry event. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Jobs can retry many times.  Do you expect onretry to be called 20 times?

Comment: Yes. My use-case is that I want to notify the user that an error occurred but also let them know that the job is retrying if it is. I realize that this would cause the callback to fire a bazillion times.

Answer (score 0):

The most workable approach is likely a server-side middleware which can detect a retry in progress for a batched job and send an email.