# Run callback before (or during) Sidekiq retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I am looking to run a callback before (or when) a retry occurs for my Sidekiq worker jobs. We store the state of our jobs as an attribute (queued, performing, completed, etc.), and retries do not automatically reset this state. I need a way to run a callback that sets the retried job's state back to `queued` before the retried job gets queued. For example:

```
before_retry do 
  self.status = "queued"
end
```

I read another post ([Sidekiq Pro callback when batch is retried?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710594/sidekiq-pro-callback-when-batch-is-retried)) suggesting some sort of server middleware to detect retries and run callbacks, but I don't entirely know if that will work as I feel the retry would already be queued by the time any middleware catches it. Are there any other options out there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to `rescue` inside `perform`?

```
def perform
  ...
rescue YourException
  self.status = "queued"
  raise
end
```

`raise`ing again so the job is retried.

Comment: I like the idea, and under normal circumstances this might work, however, the way we handle our sidekiq jobs is built with custom error handling in a universal class, and this would conflict with that. This is the main reason why we wouldn't be able to do something like this.